# How to dynamically fetch api route from component in page folder?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i have a reusable contact form that works perfectly when used in the index.js file.
However when i use it from a component in the page folder i am having a 404 not found error message because it uses this route 3000/ourServices/conciergerie/api/contact/ instead of 3000/api/contact.

How do i ensure the it will always fetch the correct route? please see how i fetch the api below :

```
 async function handleSubmit() {
    const data = {
      firstName,
      email,
      phone,
      message,
    };
    const res = await fetch("api/contact", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        data: data,
        token: "test",
      }),
    });
    alert("Message sent! Thank you\nWe will be in touch with you soon!");
  }
```

pages/ourServices/conciergerie

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { AiOutlinePlus, AiOutlineMinus } from "react-icons/ai";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { Contact } from "../../components/contact/Contact";
import es from "../../locales/es-ES/conciergerie.json";
import en from "../../locales/en-US/conciergerie.json";
import Icon1 from "/public/1.svg";
import Icon2 from "/public/2.svg";
import Icon3 from "/public/3.svg";

const Conciergerie = () => {
  let { locale } = useRouter();
  let t = locale === "es-ES" ? es : en;
  // const { t } = useTranslation(locale, "conciergerie");

  let myIcons = [Icon1, Icon2, Icon3];

  const scrollToConciergerie = () => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 300,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  };

  const myLoader = ({ src, width, quality }) => {
    return `${src}?w=${width}&q=${quality || 75}`;
  };

  const [showform, setshowform] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("load", scrollToConciergerie);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("load", scrollToConciergerie);
    };
  });

  const showContactForm = () => {
    return <Contact />;
  };

  const contentData = t.conciergerieData;

  return (
    <div className="section" onLoad={scrollToConciergerie}>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="text-center">
          <h1 className=" my-4 text-capitalize" id="conciergerie">
            {t.conciergerieHeader}
          </h1>
        </div>
        <h3 className="text-capitalize concierge-subheading mt-3">
          {t.conciergerieTitle}
        </h3>
        <p className="lead concierge-subheading-text">{t.conciergerieText}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row text-center mt-5">
          {contentData?.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <div className="col-md-4" key={index}>
                <span className="fa-stack fa-4x">
                  <Image
                    layout="responsive"
                    src={myIcons[index]}
                    alt="icons"
                    className="svg-inline--fa fa-solid  fa-stack-1x fa-inverse img-fluid"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    focusable="false"
                    data-prefix="fas"
                    data-icon="house"
                    role="img"
                    objectFit="cover"
                    height={300}
                    width={300}
                    //loader={myLoader}
                  />
                </span>
                <h4 className="my-3 text-hogar2 text-uppercase">
                  {item.title}
                </h4>
                <ul>
                  {item.text.map((text) => {
                    return (
                      <li key={text.id} className="list-unstyled">
                        <p className="m-0 text-muted text-list">
                          {text.content}
                        </p>
                      </li>
                    );
                  })}
                </ul>

                {item.id === "algomas" &&
                  (!showform ? (
                    <AiOutlinePlus
                      role="button"
                      onClick={() => {
                        setshowform(!showform);
                      }}
                      className="fs-2"
                      fill="#5ab4ab"
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <AiOutlineMinus
                      role="button"
                      onClick={() => {
                        setshowform(!showform);
                      }}
                      className="fs-2"
                      fill="#5ab4ab"
                    />
                  ))}
                {item.id === "else" &&
                  (!showform ? (
                    <AiOutlinePlus
                      role="button"
                      onClick={() => {
                        setshowform(!showform);
                      }}
                      className="fs-2"
                      fill="#5ab4ab"
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <AiOutlineMinus
                      role="button"
                      onClick={() => {
                        setshowform(!showform);
                      }}
                      className="fs-2"
                      fill="#5ab4ab"
                    />
                  ))}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        {showform && showContactForm()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Conciergerie;
```

can someone help me please?

Comment: Could you share your folder structure and where in that structure are you trying to use your contact form component? Also, how are you using it? Are you importing it from some reusable components folder or somehow differently?

Comment: Can you please post the whole index.js file code as well as the component code from which you are getting this error?

Comment: Use `fetch("/api/contact"`instead (add the /)

Comment: thanks to  you all for coming around to help.  @0xRyn have the right answer :)

Comment: Glad to help. The reason it works is paths starting with / are absolute paths, starting from the root of the project. On the other hand, your link not starting with / is a relative link starting from the file you're calling fetch from :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this problem is happening has to do with absolute and relative paths.

```js
fetch("api/contact")
```

Is a relative path. The fetch function figures out the path of the current file, ie `3000/ourServices/conciergerie`, and adds `api/contact` to it

On the other hand, if you add a "/" before the path :

```js
fetch("/api/contact")
```

Fetch figures out the root path of the project, then adds the path you added, ie :

`3000/api/contact`

TL;DR: Change `fetch("api/contact")` to `fetch("/api/contact")`.